# How can I create a skewed footer with CSS?

Tags: html, css, skew

I am trying to create a skewed footer with HTML/CSS. Here is what I have:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

footer {
  background: blue;
  height: 150px;
  transform: skew(0deg, -10deg);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Header Content</p>
</header>

<main>
  <p>Main content here</p>
</main>

<footer>
  <div id="footer-content">
    <p>Footer Content</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

There are two issues right now:

1. I don't want to have that white space in the bottom-right corner, it should be filled with blue as well.
2. I don't want the text itself inside the `footer` to be skewed. I tried to unskew just the text by doing `transform: skew(0deg, 10deg);`, but that made the text go outside the skewed footer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pLzPOg

Comment: change skew degrees along x axis

Comment: @NagaSaiA Not really, I basically want what I already have but the bottom needs to be filled as well. Basically trying to create a "slope"

Answer (score 4):

Consider linear-gradient within a pseudo-element that you put above the footer:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

footer {
  background: blue;
  height: 150px;
  position:relative;
}
footer:before {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top:-60px;
 height:60px;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49%, blue 50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Header Content</p>
</header>

<main>
  <p>Main content here</p>
</main>

<footer>
  <div id="footer-content">
    <p>Footer Content</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: This is a really interesting way to do it, gave you an upvote. Only issue is the transition from the gradient begins to show if I play around with the angle of the slope

Comment: @inhwrbp don't change the angle :) the idea is to only change the height of the pseudo element to control the angle ... height :0 --> angle :0 -- increase the height to have more angle ;)

Comment: @inhwrbp You can make the stops on the same %, eg `transparent 50%, blue 50%` to create a sharp edge

Comment: @OlexPonomarenko it won't look good in this case, we will have a kind of stairs for some height values

Comment: Oh weird, I assumed gradients are anti-aliased. #themoreyouknow

Answer (score 2):

You can make this using a CSS triangle above your footer. Alternatively, all of this could be in the `<footer>` tag, and your content with the padding + background would be wrapped in another element `.footer-content`.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

footer {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  padding: 40px;
}

.footer-border {
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 50vw solid deepskyblue;
  border-bottom: 40px solid deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-border"></div>
<footer>Content</footer>
```